# How to redirect page after reload in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some pending requests in `iframe`, when I'm try to use `assign` or `location.href` doesn't work, so I need to `location.reload(true)` then `assign` or `location.href`.

How can I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.parent.location.reload()
```

this function work to reload parent page of iframe might be work for you

Comment: yes I know this, the problem I need to assign new URL and reload, or reload then assign new URL